# forked-daapd doesn't work and I don't know why!

Tags: 11.10, server, sharing, mediaserver

I'm using ubuntu server 11.10, I've installed forked-daapd and this is its config file:

```
    general {
        # Username
        uid = "musica"
        logfile = "/var/log/forked-daapd.log"
        # Database location
        db_path = "/var/cache/forked-daapd/songs3.db"
        # Available levels: fatal, log, warning, info, debug, spam
        loglevel = spam
        # Admin password for the non-existent web interface
        admin_password = "unused"
        # Enable/disable IPv6
        ipv6 = no
}

# Library configuration
library {
        # Name of the library as displayed by the clients
        # %h: hostname, %v: version
        name = "Musica %h"
        # TCP port to listen on. Default port is 3689 (daap)
        port = 3689
        # Password for the library. Optional.
#       password = ""

        # Directories to index
        directories = { "/media/musica/" }
        # Directories containing compilations
        # Matches anywhere in the path (not a regexp, though)
#       compilations = { "/compilations/" }

        # Should iTunes metadata override ours?
#       itunes_overrides = true

        # Formats: mp4a, mp4v, mpeg, alac, flac, mpc, ogg, wma, wmal, wmav, aif, wav
        # Formats that should never be transcoded
#       no_transcode = { "alac", "mp4a" }
        # Formats that should always be transcoded
        force_transcode = { "ogg", "flac" }
}

# Local audio output
audio {
        # AirTunes name - used in the speaker list in Remote
        nickname = "Computer"
        # Audio device name for local audio output
#       card = "default"
        # Mixer channel to use for volume control - ALSA/Linux only
        # If not set, PCM will be used if available, otherwise Master.
#       mixer = ""
}

# Airport Express device
#apex "ApEx" {
        # AirTunes password
#       password = "s1kr3t"
#}
```

When I start forked-daapd this is the output:

```
    root@petra:/media/video# service forked-daapd restart
    Restarting RSP and DAAP media server:     main: Forked Media Server Version 
0.19 taking off main: Initialized with gcrypt 1.5.0
    forked-daapd.
```

And this is the log file:

```
[2012-01-03 17:18:29]     main: Forked Media Server Version 0.19 taking off
[2012-01-03 17:18:29]     main: Initialized with gcrypt 1.5.0
[2012-01-03 17:18:29]     main: PID: 12319
[2012-01-03 17:18:29]     main: mDNS init
[2012-01-03 17:18:29]     mdns: Initializing Avahi mDNS
```

The problem is banshee and rhythmbox don't see the daap server and if I manually add the daap share nothing happen!

What can I do? I've already changed the loglevel = spam but forked-daapd doesn't show any additional information in the log file